# Maps in react is rendering all of the images for all of the project instead of showing the images for one project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary, react-props

I am creating a portfolio website in react. I am trying to make it when the user click on 'view more' on a project card, there will be a pop up that shows more images of that particular project. However instead, when the user clicks 'view more' all the images for all the project is showing up on the pop up.

How do I make it so that only that images for that project shows?

Here is the code for the project card

```
  <div>
    <p>view {projectData.call_to_view}</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => setButtonPopUp(true)}>Open</button>
    <PopUp trigger={buttonPopUp} setTrigger={setButtonPopUp}></PopUp>
  </div>
```

Here is the code for the pop up

```
function PopUp(props) {

    return (props.trigger) ? (
        <div className='popup'>
            <div className='popup-inner'>
                <button className="close-btn" onClick={() => props.setTrigger(false)}>close</button>
                <h1>my pop up</h1>
                <div>
                    {allProjects.map((projectData, key) => {
                        return <PopUpContent key = {key} projectData={projectData} />;
                            })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : "";
}

export default PopUp;
```

Here is the component for the content within the pop up

```
import './PopUpContent.css';

function PopUpContent(props) {
    const {projectData} = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={projectData.image_detail1}/>
            <img src={projectData.image_detail2}/>
            <img src={projectData.image_detail3}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PopUpContent;
```

Here is my data.js. I won't spam you with all my projects - but this basically how I structured it

```
export const allProjects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        company: "Australian Association",
        year: "2019",
        title: "Congress",
        type: "website, marketing collateral, signage", 
        description: "Created pop-art themed assets for Congress, Australias leading dental conference, such as an exhibition stand, 14 exhibition features, 8 registration desk pieces, and various signs. Worked also with a developer to design the website and collaborated with other teams to meet their design needs.",
        image: "https://i.postimg.cc/CL2Q8PDn/Congress-ADA-mockup2.jpg",
        call_to_view: "assets",
        image_detail1: "https://fakeimg.pl/300x250?text=congress+image+1",
        image_detail2: "https://i.postimg.cc/CL2Q8PDn/Congress-ADA-mockup2.jpg",
        image_detail3: "https://i.postimg.cc/CL2Q8PDn/Congress-ADA-mockup2.jpg",

    },
```

I was expecting when using maps that it would only show the images from that project.

Comment: Because you are using your allProjects object to show images. You need to filter for which project you want. You can use map().filter().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the images of that particular project, why are you mapping on the `allProjects` ? In your code for `PopUp`, you are mapping on `allProjects`, and using all the objects in that array to render the images of  all the projects.

You need to make two changes.

First, remove the mapping in `PopUp` function. So change the following code

```
<h1>my pop up</h1>
<div>
  {allProjects.map((projectData, key) => {
    return <PopUpContent key = {key} projectData={projectData} />;
  })}
</div>
```

to this code

```
<h1>my pop up</h1>
<div>
  <PopUpContent key = {key} projectData={props.projectData} />
</div>
```

Now, second step is to add `projectData` as a prop in your `PopUp` component. In your project card component, I see that you already have `projectData`. Add it as a prop to `PopUp` rendering element.

```
<PopUp trigger={buttonPopUp} setTrigger={setButtonPopUp} projectData={projectData} />
```

This will use the `projectData` of a particular project element which is being passed into the popup, and the images of only that project will be shown.